# while cloning SPF12.1 sdk I am facing this issue

Tags: sdk

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master

Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
File "/data/shubham/qca-networking-2022-spf-12-1_qca_oem-r12.1_00010.3-24c5c8c657389e2af3f7af24c691f1ffb82ab86b/.repo/repo/main.py", line 79
file=sys.stderr)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tring to clone and compile SPF 12.1 SDK